# How to clear blobs under git/objects after resetting INDEX on initial commit?

Tags: git, git-index

In a clean git repo, if I add all untracked files using `git add .` then git stores all files as `blobs` under `git/objects` directory.

Now if I remove files from Index back to working directory using `git reset .` then it clears the `INDEX` however the `blobs` are still remains under `git/objects` directory.

What command to use to clear the `blobs` as well to clean the objects directory?

If not manually removed (using a command) does `git` autocleans those unused blobs?

Thanks
dk

Answer (score 0):

This low level git command did it for me `git prune --expire now`but NOT this `git gc --prune=now` or `git gc`